# unable to get hhvm working with nginx

Tags: php, nginx, hhvm

I have nginx and hhvm installed and running as processes on a ubuntu VM.  The configs are copied below.  I have an index.php file in /usr/share/nginx/html (pointed to by nginx) but when I try to access the site beign served by nginx, I get the following error about hhvm:

**/var/log/nginx/error.log**

```
2016/10/04 12:03:05 [crit] 12443#0: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/hhvm/hhvm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstr
eam, client: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/hhvm/hhvm.sock:", host: "xx.xx.xx.xx"
```

**Nginx config (part of config)**

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;       

    location / {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri/index.php$args /index.php$args;
    }

    location /mysql {
        index index.php;
    }

    location ~* \.(php)$ {
        try_files $uri = 404;
        location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {return 404;}
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_keep_conn on;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/hhvm/hhvm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
```

I have checked - bothh nginx and hhvm processes are running.  Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot this further?

Update:
I changed the server.ini file in /etc/hhvm to the following and restarted the service but it does not appear to have done the job

```
hhvm.server.file.socket=/var/run/hhvm/hhvm.sock
```

I commented out the 9000 port being used previously.

**Update:**
After making the server.init change and restarting hhvm, I get the following error in /var/log/hhvm/error.log:

```
Unable to read pid file /var/run/hhvm/pid for any meaningful pid
Unable to read pid file /var/run/hhvm/pid for any meaningful pid
Unable to read pid file /var/run/hhvm/pid for any meaningful pid
Unable to read pid file /var/run/hhvm/pid for any meaningful pid
Unable to read pid file /var/run/hhvm/pid for any meaningful pid
Unable to start page server
Shutting down due to failure(s) to bind in HttpServer::runAndExitProcess
```

The /var/run/hhvm directory is owned by www-data

Comment: Are you sure hhvm is running, and the socket file is configured correctly (`/etc/hhvm/server.ini` or similar files might be useful to diagnose the actual problem). Just read through hhvm docs [here](https://docs.hhvm.com/hhvm/advanced-usage/fastCGI)

Comment: This might be better asked on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up running hhvm on port 9000 and pointed nginx (fasgcgi_pas) to point to the port (instead of using the file socket option).

Comment: When I read your answer I realized hhvm was set to use 9000 but another application was already using it. So I changed to 9009 and it worked. Thanks!